# Display "Display name" instead of field name in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

This is my Class definition.

```
    public class Customer
    {
        [Display(Name="Customer ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Customer Name")]
        public string CusName { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my XAML code

`<DataGrid Name="DataGrid" />`

And this is data binding

```
    public Test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        List<Customer> cus = new List<Customer>();
        cus.Add(new Customer() { ID = 1, CusName = "Jackson" });
        cus.Add(new Customer() { ID = 2, CusName = "Micheal" });
        cus.Add(new Customer() { ID = 3, CusName = "Jackson" });
        DataGrid.ItemsSource = cus;
    }
```

This is the result:

[image: DataGrid Result]

The DataGrid header columns diplay the ID,CusName, they are Customer's field name.

How to make DataGrid header column display Customer ID, Customer Name instead of ID, CusNumber ? They are in [Display] attribute

Comment: this is the forth time you ask the same question. -1. Close voting

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP has been asking the same thing over and over 4 times already.

Comment: If you think the OP is abusing the system, flag for a moderator.

Comment: Link to duplicate? I can't find the duplicates, so marking to re-open. This should close as a dupe, not off-topic.

Comment: Use `DisplayName` attribute.

http://www.mindscapehq.com/forums/thread/330441

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.name?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

As you can see DataGrid doesn' really care if you properties are decorated. You can either disable the autogeneration of columns and define them manually, or leverage the AutoGeneratingColumn event

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid" AutoGeneratingColumn="grid_AutoGeneratingColumn"/>


private void grid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "ID":
                e.Column.Header = "Customer ID";
                break;

            case "CusName":
                e.Column.Header = "Customer Name";
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

You can also automate this solution by defining an attached behaviour:

```
public static class CustomColumnHeadersProperty
{
    public static DependencyProperty ItemTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ItemType",
        typeof(Type),
        typeof(CustomColumnHeadersProperty),
        new PropertyMetadata(OnItemTypeChanged));

    public static void SetItemType(DependencyObject obj, Type value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ItemTypeProperty, value);
    }

    public static Type GetItemType(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Type)obj.GetValue(ItemTypeProperty);
    }

    private static void OnItemTypeChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;

        if (args.NewValue != null)
            dataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn;
        else
            dataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn -= dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn;
    }

    static void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        var type = GetItemType(sender as DataGrid);

        var displayAttribute = type.GetProperty(e.PropertyName).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute;
        if (displayAttribute != null)
            e.Column.Header = displayAttribute.Name;
    }
}


<DataGrid x:Name="grid" local:CustomColumnHeadersProperty.ItemType="{x:Type local:MyClass}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your helping. I'm looking for an automatically solutions.

Comment: You can totaly automate this solution, using either Display or a custom defined attribute, by defining an attached behavior.

Comment: Could you explain to me more details ?