# AutoGenerateField not working in wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagridview

I am binding my datagrid to an observableCollection of Class CustomerDetails, I want to hide one of the property from being displayed on the UI as column, for which i am using AutoGenerateField to false, still this column is getting displayed in UI, what am i missing ?

my xaml file is like below :

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridItems}" 
                      Margin="1" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedItem }"
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
 public ObservableCollection<CustomerDetails> DataGridItems => _model.CustomerDetailsList;
```

Model.cs

```
 public ObservableCollection<CustomerDetails> CustomerDetailsList { get; set; }


public MyModel()
        {            
            CustomerDetailsList = new ObservableCollection<CustomerDetails>();    // assume that my list of customers is initialized here      
        }  


 public class CustomerDetails 
    {

        #region Constructor

        public CustomerDetails()
        {

        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Members        

        public string CustomerName
        {
           get; set;
        }

        public string CustomerID
        {
            get;set;
        }

        public string ProductCode
        {
            get;set;
        }
// want to hide this from getting shown in Datagrid
        [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
        public string ProductInternalId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you are running into the same underlying problem as:

- [Display "Display name" instead of field name in WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164100/display-display-name-instead-of-field-name-in-wpf-datagrid)

You should handle the AutoGeneratingColumn event to cancel the generation of the column (you can base your logic on the field attributes to still make use of [Display(AutoGenerateField=false)]):

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/customize_autogenerated_columns

Alternatively you could turn off AutoGenerateColumns and add the ones you want to the datagrid columns template manually.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the Links. I am still confused,  what's the use of [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)] , when is it supposed to work ?
My assumption was that I don't have to deal with AutoGeneratingColum event to cancel the generation of Column if I use [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)] for the property I don't want to be displayed on the UI

Comment: As far as I know, data annotations do not work natively with WPF DataGrid: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4e5ab8ac-0591-458b-a187-8c3f4ea5234d/datagrid-dataannotations-displayattribute

Answer (score 1):

The `DataGrid` in WPF doesn't check whether a property is decorated with the `DisplayProperty` so decorating your property with this attribute will have no effect.

What you should do is to either set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false` and explicitly define the columns you want in your XAML markup, or handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = e.PropertyName == "ProductInternalId ";
}
```